# XAML/Silverlight 4.0 complex form field binding

Tags: xaml, silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a datagrid in Silverlight, with the following field bound to `lastPrice`:

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Price" SortMemberPath="lastPrice" Binding="{Binding lastPrice}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

The problem is, occasionally lastPrice is less than 0, and in those cases I want to display something else (`TBD`) in the field instead of what lastPrice actually is. Is there an easy way for me to do this inside the XAML?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way to do this. You can achieve this by using a [Converter](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/15/so-what-s-a-silverlight-value-converter-anyway.aspx).